# running a test with a specific parameter value in pycharm pytest plugin

Tags: pycharm, pytest

I'm running tests from the pycharm pytest plugin and very happy with it.
However, once I finish running a test with parameters that looks like this:

```py
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("my_param", [
        "aaa",
        "bbb",
        "ccc",
    ])
    def test_it(self, my_param):
```

I often would like to re-run only the `"bbb"`, but when I right-click it and select "Run pytest" I get "no tests found in testsuite".

Is there some option/workaround I'm missing?

Comment: Works fine for me, though I use PyCharm Professional, where pytest support is build-in - I guess you use the Community version?

Comment: Community has the same pytest support. The problem sounds similar to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-31836 which was caused by spaces in test node ids. Try 2020.1 EAP build https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/nextversion/ the problem should be obsolete there.

Answer (score 0):

cli is your friend, you can select a specific parametrized test, consider keyword selector -k bbb

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: In the background pycharm runs the tests using the command line, just click on the test configuration in the top right corner and use additional arguments. In the additional arguments fill in -k bbb and only the second test will run